# Video getting stuck when playing through flash and red5

Tags: video, flash, red5

I have successfully created an application which will record webcam using flash and red5 server.

Lately I have encountered a strange issue.

When I try to play a recorded video file using flash, my video gets stuck after a specific amount of time has passed.

In researching I found out that it's an issue with Adobe Flash 11.7, so I downloaded version 11.8 and checked, but my video still gets stuck at the same point.

What might be the reason? Please help - any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have researched a lot ,but unable to find the exact cause.

Instead i used  flow player for the same purpose and it worked like charm.